# Ran npm audit fix. Now get "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' "

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

**Any chance of this being reopened please? The duplicate suggests that I'm trying to access `fs` in the browser, but I've rolled back the updates and everything is now working fine, so I don't think that's the solution. I'm updating manually now, but I assume I'm inevitably going to come across the same problem*

---

Pretty much as the title says.

Tried removing `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`, running `npm i --save fs`, `npm install`, no luck. Serves me right for not updating the packages manually I guess, but not really sure where to go from here :(

Here's the beginning of the Errors that I get (although they continue much further than this). Even a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 74:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/js/views/adminView.js
 @ ./src/js/admin.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\node_modules\destroy'
 @ ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 12:17-30
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/js/views/adminView.js
 @ ./src/js/admin.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\node_modules\etag'
 @ ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:12-25
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/js/views/adminView.js
 @ ./src/js/admin.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\node_modules\express\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 18:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/js/views/adminView.js
 @ ./src/js/admin.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\node_modules\mime'
 @ ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/js/views/adminView.js
 @ ./src/js/admin.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\node_modules\send'
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/js/views/adminView.js
 @ ./src/js/admin.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\node_modules\express\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 18:11-25
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/js/views/adminView.js
 @ ./src/js/admin.js

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src':
  Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'
  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - Compilation.js:925
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:925:10

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:401
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:130
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:224
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22

  - async.js:2830
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:2830:7

  - async.js:6877
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:6877:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:214
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25

  - Resolver.js:213
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:213:14

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43

  - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src':

  - Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - Compilation.js:925
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:925:10

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:401
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:130
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:224
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22

  - async.js:2830
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:2830:7

  - async.js:6877
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:6877:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:214
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25

  - Resolver.js:213
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:213:14

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43

  - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src':

  - Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - Compilation.js:925
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:925:10

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:401
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:130
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:224
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22

  - async.js:2830
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:2830:7

  - async.js:6877
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:6877:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:214
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25

  - Resolver.js:213
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:213:14

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5




ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src':
  Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'
  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - Compilation.js:925
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:925:10

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:401
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:130
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:224
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22

  - async.js:2830
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:2830:7

  - async.js:6877
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:6877:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:214
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25

  - Resolver.js:213
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:213:14

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43

  - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src':

  - Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - Compilation.js:925
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:925:10

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:401
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:130
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:224
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22

  - async.js:2830
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:2830:7

  - async.js:6877
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:6877:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:214
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25

  - Resolver.js:213
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:213:14

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43

  - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src':

  - Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - Compilation.js:925
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:925:10

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:401
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:130
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:224
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22

  - async.js:2830
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:2830:7

  - async.js:6877
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:6877:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:214
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25

  - Resolver.js:213
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:213:14

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src':
  Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'
  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - Compilation.js:925
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:925:10

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:401
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:130
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:224
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22

  - async.js:2830
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:2830:7

  - async.js:6877
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:6877:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:214
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25

  - Resolver.js:213
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:213:14

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43

  - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src':

  - Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - Compilation.js:925
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:925:10

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:401
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:130
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:224
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22

  - async.js:2830
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:2830:7

  - async.js:6877
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:6877:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:214
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25

  - Resolver.js:213
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:213:14

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43

  - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src':

  - Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'

  - Compilation.js:925
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:925:10

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:401
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:130
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:224
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22

  - async.js:2830
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:2830:7

  - async.js:6877
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[neo-async]/async.js:6877:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:214
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25

  - Resolver.js:213
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:213:14

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5


  - UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7

  - Resolver.js:285
    [jennings-recruitment-rebuild]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:285:5




Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
     5 assets
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_1 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_1
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_2 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_2
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_3 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_3
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_4 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_4
    [./node_modules/html-loader/dist/runtime/getUrl.js] 548 bytes {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} {HtmlWebpackPlugin_2} {HtmlWebpackPlugin_3} {HtmlWebpackPlugin_4} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/about.html] 424 bytes {HtmlWebpackPlugin_1} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/admin.html] 4.53 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_2} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/contact.html] 21.6 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_4} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html] 17.3 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/jobs.html] 9.42 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_3} [built]
    [./src/assets/legal.png] 2.89 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} {HtmlWebpackPlugin_4} [built]

    ERROR in ./src/index.html (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'
     @ ./src/index.html (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html) 3:33-65

    ERROR in ./src/admin.html (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/admin.html)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'
     @ ./src/admin.html (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/admin.html) 3:33-65

    ERROR in ./src/jobs.html (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/jobs.html)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'
     @ ./src/jobs.html (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/jobs.html) 3:33-65

    ERROR in ./src/contact.html (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/contact.html)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg' in 'C:\Users\Nick\FinalProjects\jennings-recruitment-rebuild\src'
     @ ./src/contact.html (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/contact.html) 3:33-65
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "jennings-recruitment-rebuild",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --hot --open chrome",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^9.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "svgo-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.0.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "gsap": "^3.6.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post text as text, not images of text.

Comment: I'll hunt down a duplicate in a minute but the `fs` module depends on Node.js. It can't run in a browser. You can't bundle it with Webpack and send it to a browser.

Comment: @Quentin as far as I'm aware I'm not doing that. I guess it must be a loader I'm using with webpack that's changed?

Answer (score 0):

The `fs` module is included in node.js. You do not need to install it using `npm`.
After removing the `node_modules` folder, you probably want to run `npm i` to install the packages listed in your `package.json`.